# Unwind segue and audio keeps playing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that displays fullscreen cells. And when cells automatically scroll one by one. When scrolling happens an audio file plays depends on the index number of the cell. There is no problem with this part. But my problem is that I have a back button and when user taps it user goes to main view controller. And this back button has a unwind segue. When i tap the back button i go to the main view controller but the audio file that plays when collection view cell scrolls keeps playing over and over.

I have tried this but it is not working

```
@IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if audioPlayer1.isPlaying == true {
        audioPlayer1.stop()
    }
```

And i am calling everything inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            startTimer()
        }
```

This is the part handles automatically scrolls to the next cell. And i am calling `alphabetSoundPlay()` function here.

```
func scrollToNextCell(){

            let cellSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            let contentOffset = myCollectionView.contentOffset
            myCollectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: contentOffset.x + cellSize.width, y: contentOffset.y, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height), animated: true)
            alphabetSoundPlay()
            }
```

3 seconds delay for scrolling

```
func startTimer() {

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(scrollToNextCell),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)
    }
```

This is the function figures out which cell it is and which audio file will play

```
func alphabetSoundPlay() {

        let currentRow = self.myCollectionView.indexPath(for: self.myCollectionView.visibleCells[0])?.row

        if currentRow == 0 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:alphabetSound1!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer1.play()
        } else if currentRow == 1 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:alphabetSound2!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer2.play()
        }else if currentRow == 2 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer3 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:alphabetSound3!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer3.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer3.play()
        }else if currentRow == 3 {
            do
            {
                audioPlayer4 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:alphabetSound4!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                return print("file not found")
            }
            audioPlayer4.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer4.play()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `unwind()` function doesn't deallocate your viewController instance. You can't access viewController instance technically anymore but it's memory instance stay still on memory and let your AudioPlayer keep playing. Try using

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
   [unowned self] () -> Swift.Void in
   self.yourPlayer.stop();
   self.yourPlayer = nil;
 })
```

or stop and deallocate your audioPlayers inside your `unwind()` segue function.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines in prepareForSegue method

```
if audioPlayer1.isPlaying == true {
    audioPlayer1.stop()
```

And also be sure that you are calling stop() method on the same instance of audio player which is playing currently.